# Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

```
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.
Extracted source (around line #23):                  

        <td><%= localize(movie.release_date, format: :long) %></td>
```

when I try to save with the blank date this error occurs, is there a strong textsolution where I can save without needing to fill it?

**EDIT:**

[image: my browser]

**==========================================================================**

[image: my terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a default value to `localize`:

```
<td><%= localize(movie.release_date, format: :long, default: '-') %></td>
```

The default value is returned whenever the first argument is `nil`.

Comment: Nice. OP, this answer is better than mine for your scenario.

Comment: nice, thks Stefan! :D u and Amadan helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After you try to save `movie` and it fails, look at the resulting error, and also display the errors on that object, e.g.

```
movie.errors.full_messages
```

That should give you more details about why it failed.

Comment: look, I put some images now, browser and terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your `localize` hates `nil` values, so don't give it one.

Hacky but short:

```
<td><%= movie.release_date && localize(movie.release_date, format: :long) %></td>
```

Nice and long:

```
<% unless movie.release_date.nil? %>
  <td><%= localize(movie.release_date, format: :long) %></td>
<% end %>
```